# csrf token missing when using django Views

Tags: django, django-views, django-login

When I am submitting a login form for a normal user or for admin. I get the following error

CSRF token missing or incorrect.

The interesting things when I use a custom view for registering everything is fine. I tried to swap the urls from my custom projects to the one created by django initially and neither options work
login.html

```
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset">
            <legend>Log In</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="logBu">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

urls.py

```
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', Builtviews.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', Builtviews.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='main/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```

Ive cleared out all my cookies. Ive even added a csrf_trusted origins as well as CORS to settings but nothing works.
I even downgraded django since i read this is a 4.0.0 thing and that didnt work either.
settings.py

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login?next=/admin/',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login?next=/profile/',
     #Encrypted version
    'https://127.0.0.1:8080/admin',
    'https://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login',
    'https://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login?next=/admin/',
    'https://127.0.0.1:8000/login',
    'https://127.0.0.1:8000/login/',
    'https://127.0.0.1:8000/login?next=/profile/'
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
]
```

I have added corsheaders to installed apps as well as the appropriate things to middlewear

Comment: How do you generate the token?

Comment: Django generates it for you when you put {% csrf_token %}